# Query for making sale report

Tags: sql, mysql

I have database schema of order_lines as

```
product_id, quantity, created_at
```

I want to query result like

```
date               1 2 3 4 5 ..
product 1 count    2 ...  
product 2 count    5 ...
```

Is it possible to do this in mySQL ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I a cross tab query should do the trick.

This might be helpful:
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,110464,110464

http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/10/creating-crosstabs-in-mysql.html

Answer (score 0):

```
select product_id, sum(quantity) from order_lines group_by product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution.  You may need to modify it to suit your needs:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`.`ordertotals` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`.`ordertotals` ()
BEGIN
  DECLARE `xtab_qry` VARCHAR(4096) DEFAULT '';

  SELECT CONCAT('SELECT o.product_id ',
                 GROUP_CONCAT(
                     DISTINCT
                     CONCAT(', SUM(IF(o.created_at="', ol.created_at,
                            '",o.quantity,null)) AS "',
                            DATE_FORMAT(ol.created_at, "%m/%d/%Y"),
                            '"')
                      ORDER BY ol.created_at
                      SEPARATOR ''
                     ),
                     ' FROM orderlines o WHERE 1 GROUP BY o.product_id'
             ) AS stuff
        INTO
            @xtab_qry
        FROM
            orderlines ol
        WHERE 1;

        PREPARE my_sql_statement
        FROM @xtab_qry;

        EXECUTE my_sql_statement;

        DEALLOCATE
        PREPARE my_sql_statement;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

With this test data:

```
product_id  quantity    created_at
1           4           2009-09-14
1           5           2009-09-14
2           2           2009-09-14
3           3           2009-09-13
1           9           2009-09-15
1           2           2009-09-16
```

It produced these results:

```
product_id  09/13/2009  09/14/2009  09/15/2009  09/16/2009
1                       9           9           2
2                       2       
3           3
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT:
In summary, what this does is to create a stored procedure that generates a dynamic SQL string.  It then executes that query.  This is why this needs to be in a stored procedure.  indiecompanyllc pointed to a great article that I used a while ago to learn how to do this.  Here is that link: http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/10/creating-crosstabs-in-mysql.html.

Comment: Look like results I looking for, but I don't understand those command = = could you tell me what article I needed to understand the code.

Comment: Just edited my response a bit... Check http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/10/creating-crosstabs-in-mysql.html for some more info.